# Duplicated object that reflects changes in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been using Sketch recently and they have this really nice concept of grouped objects that can be cloned.

When you make a change to the master group item it reflects the other items. Optionally you can make changes to children like text by holding CMD.

Just wondering if this is possible in illustrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Symbols

Create a symbol by dragging the artowrk to the Symbols panel.

Place an instance of your symbol by dragging it from the Symbols panel.

Since Illustrator CC 2015 you can now define your symbol as a *Dynamic Symbol*. Any changes to instances of a dynamic symbol won't be reflected in the master symbol, but any changes in the master will be reflected in any instances, which allows you to override elements without breaking the link to the symbol.

You can read more about symbols here:

- [Illustrator Help / How to work with Symbols](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/symbols.html)

Comment: Unfortunately they took away the ability to he nested symbols which was frigging awesome.

Comment: So you can't do nested symbols?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns you can pre CC-2015 (I believe). I'm not sure if its intended or if its a bug, there are a number of posts on the adobe forums claiming its a bug, and the help docs do mention nested symbols still.

Comment: Any idea if its a bug or not @joojaa ?

Comment: @Cai no its a feature they said they would remove it